# form options not populating

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In a spring mvc app, the following code is not populating a drop down list as it should:

```
<form:select path="medication.doseformSelected">
    <form:option value="-1">Select a dose form</form:option>
    <form:options items="${doseforms}" itemLabel="str" itemValue="rxaui" />
</form:select>
```

Here is the html that results from the above code:

```
<form:select path="medication.doseformSelected">
    <form:option value="-1">Select a dose form</form:option>
    <form:options items="[Mouthwash, Solution, Tablet, Toothpaste, Cream, Foam]" itemLabel="str" itemValue="rxaui" />  
</form:select>
```

As you can see, the option items are populating as a list that is invisible in the user's browser unless they view source.

**How can I change the code so that it will populate the drop down list correctly?**

For reference, here is the complete list of taglibs referenced at the top of the jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="datatables" uri="http://github.com/dandelion/datatables" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="joda" uri="http://www.joda.org/joda/time/tags" %>
```

What else do I need to post for you to see the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Spring's `form` tag library produces HTML `<form>` elements, so if this

```
<form:select path="medication.doseformSelected">
    <form:option value="-1">Select a dose form</form:option>
    <form:options items="[Mouthwash, Solution, Tablet, Toothpaste, Cream, Foam]" itemLabel="str" itemValue="rxaui" />  
</form:select>
```

appears in the HTML source you see in a browser, it means the JSP Servlet did not use the `form` tag library to render it and just wrote it to the response directly (after resolving the EL).

You seem to be missing

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
```

Also, you seem to have a number of duplicate tag libraries declared.